# Snow Leopard error: "no default application specified to open the document Growl.prefPane"

Tags: macos, mac, growl

Why would this error occur when attempting to install Growl? And what should I do to get past this issue?

```
There is no default application specified to open the document Growl.prefPane
```

First, I tried upgrading Growl and received that message. I then uninstalled Growl, tried doing a fresh install, and still received it.

I also tried running the following (resetting Launch Services) in the terminal, then installing Growl, with the same result:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user /
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a bit surprised that rebuilding your Launch Services database did not fix the problem. Maybe there is another application (besides *System Preferences*) that is trying to claim the `prefPane` extension.

If you could install preference panes, I would suggest the use of [*RCDefaultApp*](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) to check and/or reset the association between the `prefPane` extension and the *System Preferences* application.

You might try dragging your `prefPane` file (bundle, really) onto the dock icon of (an already running instance of) *System Preferences* instead of just opening it through *Finder*.

The “manual” installation method would be to just copy the `prefPane` bundle to `~/Library/PreferencePanes/` or `/Library/PreferencePanes/`. This may work to install it, but it will not fix your association problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restarting after resetting your Launch Services? (What the Terminal command you posted did)

This does not fix your issue but as a workaround:

Preference Panes can be installed in `~/Library/PreferencePanes/` or `/Library/PreferencePanes`.

Does `open -a "/Applications/System Preferences.app" /PATH/TO/Growl.prefPane` work?